# What model should I use to fit an arbitrary continuous distribution for each data point?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, mixed-model, loss-functions

My problem is, for each input data $x$ I have some corresponding output samples $y\sim p(y|x)$, where $p(y|x)$ can be an arbitrary continuous distribution.

I don't think a least squares model will work, because say if $p(y|x)$ has two peaks then least squares is likely to find some midpoint between the peaks. Probably an "[exclusive divergence](https://timvieira.github.io/blog/post/2014/10/06/kl-divergence-as-an-objective-function/)" loss will work better as at least it can find one peak.
[image]

I have in mind two solutions, the first is to use a Gaussian mixture model to fit more peaks.

The second is to discretize the space into cells, then hopefully somehow it can be solved as a classification problem.

What is the common approach for such problems? Are there any examples/papers to look at?
Thanks in advance :)

**Update**
Some clarification updates (thanks user20160 for the questions)
1) $x$ and $y$ are both high dimensional continuous vectors
2) there might be probably less than ten $y$s for each $x$, so I don't think it's enough to estimate a distribution separately for each each $x$
3) I need to estimate a function over the whole input space that gives $p(y∣x)$ for any $x$, instead of a fixed set of observed $x$ values.

Jan Kukacka's answer mentioned variational inference, it's not clear to me how it could be applied to my problem.

Comment: Is x 1-dimensional?

Comment: @Denziloe no, but I'd love to hear any suggestions for the 1-dimensional case as well, thanks

Comment: 1) Is $y$ a scalar or vector? Is $x$ real or discrete? 2) It sounds like you have multiple/repeated samples at each $x$ value. How many? 3) Is the problem to estimate $p(y \mid x)$ at a fixed set of observed $x$ values, or do you need to estimate a function over the whole input space that gives $p(y \mid x)$ for any $x$?

Comment: @user20160 hi thanks for replying, 1) $x$ and $y$ are both hd continuous vectors, 2) there might be probably less than ten $y$s for an $x$, so I don't think it's enough to estimate a distribution using only less than ten samples, 3) I need to estimate a function over the whole input space that gives $p(y∣x)$ for any $x$ :)

Answer (score 5):

**I think you are looking for Variational inference.**

Shortly, Variational inference is trying to find a function $q(y)$ approximating (intractable) $p(y|x)$. It relies on optimization of the (exclusive) $\mathrm{KL}(q||p)$ that you mentioned, so in multimodal case it will converge to a single mode. As Variational inference texts never forget to mention, you reduce an intractable inference problem to optimization (tuning parameters of $q$).

There are good introductory chapters on VI in *K. Murphy: Machine Learning, A Probabilistic Perspective*, Chap. 21, and in *C. Bishop: Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning*, Chap. 10. For more in-depth overview, see for example *[Blei et al.: Variational Inference: A Review for Statisticians](https://arxiv.org/abs/1601.00670)*. There are more great tutorials by David Blei around the internet.